# Vim equalprg: why does it fail silently on a bash script?

Tags: formatting

After the command `:set equalprg=echo.sh`, the equals command simply deletes the specified region. Here is `echo.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1"
```

Where is the input? I can assign `equalprg` to something like `astyle` and it works fine, taking text from vim on `stdin`. So why is there nothing on `stdin` for a bash script? The same thing happens when setting `formatprg` to a bash script too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$1` isn't stdin. It's the first argument passed to the script.

There's various different ways to [read from stdin in bash](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=stdin+bash). Here's [one](http://mockingeye.com/blog/2013/01/22/reading-everything-stdin-in-a-bash-script/):

```
VALUE=$(cat)
echo "$VALUE"
```